# I want to sort an array and do not know what went wrong.

Tags: c++

I do not know what is wrong with the code, it even overwrites numbers

```
 for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        for (j=i+1; j<n; j++){ 
            if(a[i]<a[j])
                temp=a[i];    *// It is not working properly*
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
        }
```

Comment: `std::sort(a, a + N);` where `N` is the length of the array.

Comment: take a simple example and debug step by step

Comment: @juanchopanza inb4 this is homework and cant use algorithms

Comment: @Borgleader Possibly. But that kind of artificial requirement should be stated in the question.

Comment: I recommend you to grab and read a book in your preffered language about C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza I couldn't agree more. I was just pointing out the likelyhood of that being a hidden requirement. This is assignment season after all.

Comment: Oblivious has the Obvious bug.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't Python, you need to enclose multiple statements in braces in order for them to all be executed only when the condition of the `if` is met.

```
if(a[i]<a[j])
{
    temp=a[i];    *// It is not working properly*
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
}
```